# BLOB image only displays when uploaded in phpMyAdmin, not displaying when uploaded via HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

When I upload BLOB images through an HTML form, even though they are stored in the database, the images are not displayed on the corresponding table. When I upload the BLOB images through phpMyAdmin, they are displayed properly. It looks like when uploading through the form, the BLOB images are significantly smaller than the ones being uploaded via phpMyAdmin. I am using Laravel routes and views.

Here is a screenshot of the phpMyAdmin table. The first two BLOBs (212.1 KiB and 214.6 KiB)  were uploaded via phpMyAdmin, and the last two (11 B and 10 B) were uploaded through the HTML form.

[phpMyAdmin BLOB comparisons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxtdf.png)

Here is my submission form in submit.blade.php:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('image') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image" placeholder="Image" value="{{ old('image') }}">
        @if($errors->has('image'))
           <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Here is how it is displayed in welcome.blade.php

```
@foreach ($event as $event)
  <table class='w100'> 
    <tr>
      <td class='w50' colspan=2 rowspan=6><img src= "data:image/png;base64,{{ chunk_split(base64_encode($event->image)) }}" height="100" width="100"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
@endforeach
```

I have a feeling it's an issue with how I'm getting the files in submit.blade.php, but I'm not sure how to properly go about fixing this.

Comment: You forgot to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your `<form>` tag , add it and see once .

Comment: @Swati thanks for replying. I added the enctype to the form tag, but unfortunately it is still not showing the images. In the database table it is now showing the uploads as BLOB - 14 B, when it should be ~270 KiB. I have updated my code to reflect the changes.